# Excel Ambiguous name detected

Tags: microsoft-excel

hi in this work book i have this code

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
 'Stop execution when workbook closes
 On Error Resume Next
 Application.OnTime Heure, "Calcul", , False
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 'start execution when workbook opens
 Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:05:00"), "Calcul"
End Sub
```

and in module 1 i have this code

```
    Sub Calcul()
     Heure = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")
     Application.OnTime Heure, "Calcul"
     Sheet1.Range("FA99666").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheet1.[o5]
     Sheet1.Range("FE99666").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheet1.[o6]
     Sheet1.Range("FI99666").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheet1.[o7]
     Sheet1.Range("FM99666").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheet1.[o8]
     Sheet1.Range("FQ99666").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheet1.[o9]
end sub
```

]
the above code runs every 5 minutes

in module 2 i would like this code to run every 10 minutes

```
    Sub Calcul()
     Heure = Now + TimeValue("00:10:00")
     Application.OnTime Heure, "Calcul"
     Sheet2.Range("FA99666").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheet2.[o5]
     Sheet2.Range("FE99666").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheet2.[o6]
     Sheet2.Range("FI99666").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheet2.[o7]
     Sheet2.Range("FM99666").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheet2.[o8]
     Sheet2.Range("FQ99666").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Sheet2.[o9]
end sub
```

but i get error -Ambiguous name detected.
im new to excel any help would be great.

Comment: Probably because you have 2 different subroutines called `Calcul`. Why don't you just have one and pass in an argument for the time increase?

Comment: sorry but i have no idea how to do that, could you show me an example please

Comment: {sigh} then perhaps you should be reading basic VBA tutorials instead of trying to run before you can walk. [Excel VBA Programming - Passing values to a Subroutine](https://www.homeandlearn.org/passing_values_to_a_sub.html)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the sentiment in the comments, you should read up, but I do not see any relevance to the specific situation because you are using `Application.OnTime` and I didn't see it mentioned share in the link.

> You can read about it here:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439866/multiple-variable-arguments-to-application-ontime

To summarize: you'll need to build a string encapsulated by quotes.  The exact construction of which is determined by the contents you're sending (e.g. variable, integer, string).

The structure is critical. In all likelihood, you'll miss one character and spend a good amount of time using trial and error until you land upon the correct string